# bitbucket persmission denied (publickey)

Tags: git, ssh, bitbucket

I have 2 repo's on bitbucket.

I have normal access rights to one repo (via SSH which I configured in the bitbucket account SSH settings) but I cannot clone the other repo (see error message in the title).

```
C:\Users\Piotr\wizytowka>git status
On branch master
nothing to commit, working directory clean

C:\Users\Piotr\wizytowka>git pull
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Answer (score 0):

Whats is the protocol that you are working with?

---

#### Http

Read only for clone usually

---

#### HTTPS

Read/write - you will be prompt for password (unless you have it in your configuration)

---

#### SSH

Read write with out any prompt for credentials.

---

In your case i assume that you are using ssh and you did not set any ssh key.

**[Here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/set-up-ssh-for-git-728138079.html)** & [here](https://websculpt.wordpress.com/2013/05/04/svn-configuring-git-on-windows-for-bitbucket/) are few guides on how to set the ssh keys for bitbucket.

Comment: as far as I get it I have already set multiple SSH keys, each for different repository

Comment: You can use the same key for all your repositories. ssh authenticate the source machine not resource